# Preprocessing data fetched via a IDataReader before returning it to other code

Tags: c#, .net

I need to massage the data fetched via a .NET **IDataReader** (returned from database) before letting other code process this data. Is there any recommended patters/existing code available?

I am thinking, I should implement my own IDataReader, encapsulating the "source IDataReader" and as the user calls Read on my reader, massage retrieved data before returning it.

Comment: I've not tried what you've suggested before. It sounds reasonable. One thing to keep in mind is might also want to inherit from DbDataReader. It has a few extra niceties that the consuming code might be expecting which IDataReader doesn't expose, like ReadAsync. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223697(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might do something like this.  The other code could get strongly-typed objects as opposed to a generic reader.  Also, since the datareader is streamable, you can also stream your objects out by retuning an IEnumerable.  This would allow you to process data as it is still being read (and even parallelize the operation, if appropriate or necessary).

The GetYourObjectFromDrFunction() would obviously do the massaging that you need and produce an instance of YourObject.

```
public IEnumerable<YourObject> GetEm()
{
    // assume we have your IDataReader named dr

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        yield return GetYourObjectFromDrFunction(dr);
    }
}
```